# ClickEvent Query

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a form with text boxes that view data from a data grid view on another form. When the form opens it displays the selected data from the table in the text boxes and trims the text so its readable.
I can delete the data from the database from this form via button, and have a button to close the form.
I'd like to have an edit button, so I can change the text in the text boxes and click save.
So far when I click edit, the close button text changes to cancel, but still closes the form, this is what I want. I'd like to change the text on the edit button to update. And when click it updates the data. Is it possible to have 2 ClickEvents for one button, one to start editing and another to update the record? Or would it be better to have a hidden button show and the edit button to be hidden?

```
public partial class viewForm : Form
{
    DataRowView Data = null;
    public viewForm(DataRowView dr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Data = dr;
        }

    private void closeBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();
    }

    private void viewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refTxt.Text = Data["Reference"].ToString().Trim();
        firstTxt.Text = Data["First Name"].ToString().Trim();
        surenameTxt.Text = Data["Surename"].ToString().Trim();
        address1Txt.Text = Data["Address Line 1"].ToString().Trim();
        address2Txt.Text = Data["Address Line 2"].ToString().Trim();
        countyTxt.Text = Data["County"].ToString().Trim();
        postTxt.Text = Data["Post Code"].ToString().Trim();
        contactTxt.Text = Data["Contact Number"].ToString().Trim();
        emailTxt.Text = Data["Email Address"].ToString().Trim();
    }

    private void deleteBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Customer information will be perminantly deteled. Do you with to continue? ", "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
            string Query = "delete from customersTBL where Reference ='" + this.refTxt.Text + "';";
            SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring);
            SqlCeCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            SqlCeDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Customer information has been deleted", "Deleted Sucessfully");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Please exit the Customers window and re-open to update the table");
                this.Close();
                //displays a system error message if a problem is found
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    private void editBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        surenameTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        address1Txt.ReadOnly = false;
        address2Txt.ReadOnly = false;
        countyTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        contactTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        emailTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        postTxt.ReadOnly = false;
        closeBTN.Text = "Cancel";
        deleteBTN.Hide();

    }




}
```

Comment: Can you add some code? My eyes kinda glazed over at your block of text.

Comment: All of the forms code(so far) added

Comment: No you could have only one event for the click button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't have two events for the same button, however, you could do different actions depending on the button text. The following code is just to demonstrate the possibility, I am not sure to have really understood your scenario, but you could easily adapt from here

```
private void editBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool notEditable = true;
    if(editBTN.Text == "Update")
    {
        UpdateDataBase();
        editBTN.Text = "Edit";
        deleteBTN.Visible = True;
        notEditable = true;
    }
    else
    {
        deleteBTN.Visible = false;
        editBTN.Text = "Update";
        deleteBTN.Visible = False;
        notEditable = false;
    }
    firstTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    surenameTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    address1Txt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    address2Txt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    countyTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    contactTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    emailTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
    postTxt.ReadOnly = notEditable;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it could work, I'll try both methods and see which one I prefer! Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly, just what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an event raised from a single button click may have some logic as such:

```
void MyButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if(((Button)sender).Text == "Save"){
      // do this
   } else {
      // do that
   }
}
```

However, I find this in bad form. I would most likely swap out controls in the main form.

Otherwise, you could have 2 buttons where you switch `.Visible = true/false` as needed.
If you decide to use Visibility to distinguish between buttons, you may find that as you continue this practice, you cannot find controls on the Designer.

My practice is to build different `UserControl`s for specific functionality. I have done so even with something as simple as requiring 2 buttons. This keeps code responsibility within the scope of the control itself.

```
//Psuedo-code
if(operation == Edit) {
   MyPanel.Load(EditControls);
} else if (operation == Save) {
   MyPanel.Load(SaveControls);
}
```

Comment: I think i'm going to go with the switching between visible and hidden buttons, keep the code simple. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: The problem with hiding controls resides in the Designer itself. One control will sit directly over another - I find this annoying :)
I have often used `UserControl`s and swap them.